# Upsert to mongodb with different criteria for update and insert

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a collection of documents where each document contains a counter as below:

```
{_id: 'a', CurrentCount: 0 }
```

I would like to:

1. If the document with the given Id does not exist, create it and set CurrentCount to 0, else go to 2
2. Increment CurrentCount only if CurrentCount is equal to a given value. If CurrentCount value does not equal to the given value, do not update the document

Currently I perform a FindOneAndUpdate, with filters on id and expected value of CurrentCount, and an Update statement that increments CurrentCount. If the document exists but CurrentCount does not equal expected value, the unique index on _id will cause upsert to throw an exception, which I catch and attribute to an incorrect counter.

I am looking for a way to do this is a single query to the db without having to rely on exceptions.

Is there any way to construct a query that would upsert solely based on Id, and update only if CurrentCount is equal to expected value, and return the (potentially) changes version of the document?

I am using Mongo 3.x, with the C# driver

Comment: Use a dummy upsert: db.myCol.update( {_id: 'a'}, {$inc : {CurrentCount: 0} }, { upsert: true }) And with the respont of that upsert you can check if it inserted or updated a document (WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 1, "nModified" : 0, "_id" : "b" })). If it said nMatch:1, you can make the real update: db.myCol.update( {_id: 'b', CurrentCount:17}, {$inc : {CurrentCount: 1} })

Comment: I am looking for a way to do this is a single query, otherwise handling the exception would be cheaper than sending a second request.